# Share to Twitter and Facebook not working on iOS

Tags: photoswipe

Sharing to Twitter and Facebook works on Desktop, but doesn's seem to work on iOS. After tapping the share icon the popup zooms, but nothing else happens.
Reproduce on http://photoswipe.com/
Is there anything to be configured on the iOS Device?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing to Twitter works fine on my iPad, but sharing to Facebook fails.

To get sharing to Facebook working, replace under iOS http://www.facebook.com by http://m.facebook.com.

In my [jAlbum PhotoSwipe skin](http://jalbum.net/en/skins/skin/PhotoSwipe) I have a more smart Facebook Share function which displays the photo on Facebook, see the [PhotoSwipe sample album](http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Reestdal_PS/).